# sencha:unable to generate apk

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, apk

I am trying to generate apk file from sencha touch application using the following [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/native_packaging) and it while giving the following command `sencha app SampApp generate <configTemplate.json>` it shows the following error.

```
C:\Users\****\Downloads\sencha-touch-2.2.1-commercial\touch-2.2.1>sencha app
SampApp generate <configTemplate.json>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

**EDIT-NEW ERROR**

now i got config.json generated.
but when i edit the config file and run the command `sencha app package configFile.json` it gives error

```
[ERR] Unknown command: "configFile.json"
```

**Edit 2**

Sorry i was wrong, i had mistakenly used generate command to generate config.json
here i my actual error comming

```
C:\Users\krishna\Downloads\sencha-touch-2.2.1-commercial\touch-2.2.1>sencha -d a
pp package  config.json
[DBG] Loading configuration from C:\Users\krishna\Downloads\sencha-touch-2.2.1-c
ommercial\touch-2.2.1
[DBG] Loading build environment from directory C:\Users\krishna\Downloads\sencha
-touch-2.2.1-commercial\touch-2.2.1
[DBG] Detecting framework plugin
[DBG] resolving framework config overrides for 'touch'
[DBG] Detected framework version 2.2.1.480
[DBG] failed to detect C:\Users\krishna\Downloads\sencha-touch-2.2.1-commercial\
touch-2.2.1\cmd\plugin.xml
[DBG] defaulting to 'current' plugin
[DBG] using framework plugin located at 'C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.3
42\plugins\touch\current'
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[DBG] Loading CommandProviders
[DBG] Scanning for extensions in C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\exten
sions
[DBG] loading extension from C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extension
s\sencha-compass
[DBG] Loaded extension sencha-compass
[DBG] loading extension from C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extension
s\sencha-io
[DBG] Loaded extension sencha-io
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\ex
tensions\sencha-compass for extensions
[DBG] Located C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensions\sencha-compas
s\sencha-compass.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-compass\sencha-compass.jar
[DBG] get value lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar lib/ant-1.8.4.jar lib/ant-launcher-1.8.4
.jar for manifest class path
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-compass\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-compass\lib\ant-1.8.4.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-compass\lib\ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishn
a/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-compass/sencha-compass.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishn
a/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishn
a/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/ant-1.8.4.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-compass' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishn
a/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-compass/lib/ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar!
/
[DBG] Scanning extensions directory C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\ex
tensions\sencha-io for extensions
[DBG] Located C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensions\sencha-io\sen
cha-io.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\sencha-io.jar
[DBG] get value lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/commo
ns-codec-1.6.jar lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar lib/httpm
ime-4.2.1.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar lib/gson-2.2.1.jar for manifest class path

[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\httpclient-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\httpcore-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\httpmime-4.2.1.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
[DBG] loading manifest for jar C:\Users\krishna\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.2.342\extensi
ons\sencha-io\lib\gson-2.2.1.jar
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/sencha-io.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/httpmime-4.2.1.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar!/
[DBG] Add extension classpath entry 'sencha-io' : jar:file:/C:/Users/krishna/bin
/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/extensions/sencha-io/lib/gson-2.2.1.jar!/
[ERR] Unknown command: "config.json"
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.findCommand(Commands.java:79)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:59)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `package` as they explain it.  You should actually use the word `package`, not the name of your app package.

```
sencha app package generate configTemplate.json
```

Comment: thankyou, it worked and now new error is comming in generating apk

Comment: You should use exactly what I typed, `sencha app package generate configTemplate.json`.  `generate` is the command that needs to be run, and `configTemplate.json` is the file it will create. The `<>` are placeholders that suggest you should put your file name there without the `<>`

Comment: i even tried this command sencha app package generate configTemplate.json it is also saying same error

Comment: now it was working fine.some typo in command for config file name and also i used debugging option with sencha command

Comment: Type `sencha app package` to see the options that you can run: `build`, `generate`, and `run`.  You MUST include one of these options.  You are probably looking for `build` at this point.